# Getting email from LinkedIn Javascript API reliably

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

Keen to get at the user's email reliably, there doesn't appear to be anything in the API documentation about this from LinkedIn. I have the cod working which grabs the basic profile and I've tried what I can find on the web to get additional fields. But this doesn't return anything. Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: 11111111111
    onLoad:  onLinkedInLoad
    authorize: true
    scope: r_basicprofile

  </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  // Setup an event listener to make an API call once auth is complete
    function onLinkedInLoad() {


        IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", getProfileData);
    }

    // Handle the successful return from the API call
    function onSuccess(data) {
        console.log(data);

    }

    // Handle an error response from the API call
    function onError(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

    // Use the API call wrapper to request the member's basic profile data
    function getProfileData() {
    var fields = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'emailAddress'];

       IN.API.Profile("me").fields(fields).result(onSuccess).error(onError);
    }
</script>
```

and HTML:

```
<script type="in/Login"></script>
```

I do not know if it is possible with the current version to return the email or the email is user setting so varies with each user.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing r_emailaddress to the scope:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
       api_key: 11111111111
       onLoad:  onLinkedInLoad
       authorize: true
       scope: r_basicprofile r_emailaddress
</script>
```

Also be sure you are using the right syntax for the fields:

```
var fields = ['first-name', 'last-name', 'email-address'];
```

And finally check in your app setting on LinkedIn developer that you grant r_emailaddress access.

Comment: Have the fields been updated - I thought it was 'lastName' etc etc.